# Emacs -- Increment internal time by x number of days + or -

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to increment internal time by x number of days (positive or negative) *without* converting it to days or seconds and then back again?

If we examine the following example of internal time format:

```
(apply 'encode-time (decode-time (current-time)))
```

We obtain a result that looks like this:

```
(21433 63163)
```

Comment: Have a look in `time-date.el`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`time-add`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Calculations.html) defined in [`time-date.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/calendar/time-date.el):

```
(time-add my-time (days-to-time days))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest! There is also `days-to-time` etc.